# Writing a new delegate object vs using a view controller as the delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This is more a question of what is generally good practice in iPhone coding.

I have a scroll view with UISegmentedControls, submit buttons, UIActionSheets, zooming, and close buttons that show temporarily.

Should I just be piling all of the method calls (target-action for UIControls) (which are not really formal delegate methods) and zooming delegate methods for UIScrollViews into this one view controller? Or would it better practice to create a new [delegate] object to handle the functionality of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, best place for all this is a view controller.

My idea is that according to MVC model, managing UIControl's action or some zooming is neither a work with data (M) or some displaying (V), so there is only one place for this - controller (C).

Of course if some UIControl event causes data-management, you should (ideologically) do it in model, but model methods should be called from controller anyhow. I think it's not the best way to make direct connection `view<->model`.

Comment: Could you give some examples of when a new subclass should be made for the delegate instead of using a view controller? I may have this completely wrong conceptually -- that delegate methods are SUPPOSED to be implemented in view controllers. (since delegates are controllers (C))

Comment: @bierko No, I can't. I thinks it is a bad idea. Technically, non-controller objects can be the delegates (you can implement protocol at model class, for example, then add object to you xib and make it a delegate - but it brakes MVC idea, I think).    And about controllers-in-controllers - I can imagine only one case, where it can be useful - if you have enormous amount of actions (simply to group them). But I think in iPhone dev such situation is more theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need. 
The idea of delegate encourage people to create a new class to handle more.But in most of cases, it's convenient to implement the delegate methods in the view controller.For example, you might want to use instance variables in the delegate methods.